# Problema SQL con distinct y count

Tags: mysql, sql, hql, hive

Tengo dos tablas, la primera llamada question_tags_g3 y la segunda questions_g3.
En la tabla question_tags_g3 el campo tag contiene lenguajes de programación y algunos se repiten muchas veces, y al ejecutar esta sentencia:

```
select a.tag, count(a.tag) as contador, b.creation_date 
from question_tags_g3 a, questions_g3 b 
where a.id=b.id and 
      b.creation_date > '2009-01-01' and 
      creation_date < '2017-01-01' 
group by b.creation_date, a.tag 
order by contador desc limit 50;
```

me saca:

```
Javascript 204019
Javascript 199471
Javascript 196340
Javascript 195340
Javascript 193540
...
```

¿Qué tendría que modificar para que no se me repitiesen los valores Javascript y solo me aparezcan los 50 lenguajes que más se repitan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, no tiene mucho sentido el poner `creation_date` en tu consulta, y menos aún agrupar por esa columna. Si quieres obtener por ejemplo la mínima fecha de creación, entonces usa `MIN`.

Por otro lado, te conviene usar `COUNT(DISTINCT columna)` en vez de simplemente `COUNT`.

Finalmente, trata de usar joins explícitos en vez de esta antigua forma de joins implícitos:

```
SELECT  a.tag, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.tag) as contador, 
        MIN(b.creation_date) as min_creation_date
FROM question_tags_g3 a
INNER JOIN questions_g3 b 
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE  b.creation_date > '2009-01-01' 
and creation_date < '2017-01-01' 
GROUP BY a.tag 
ORDER BY contador DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Perfecto, veo el código mucho más claro ahora aunque creo que seguiría existiendo el mismo problema porque al no tener distinct el a.tag pues saldría de nuevo Javascript con diferentes valores ¿no?
                                                                                                                                                  
Y por otro lado al tener el count ese distinct si por ejemplo tengo dos valores que son html 10030 y javascript 10030 no me mostraría los dos ya que sería el mismo count ¿verdad?

Comment: @FelipeJiménezPrieto no, estás confundiendo lo que hace `GROUP BY` con lo que hace `DISTINCT`. Prueba el código que puse para que puedas ver los resultados que obtienes

Comment: Todo correcto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: @FelipeJiménezPrieto si la respuesta de Lamak ha resuelto tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada. Consulta en el centro de ayuda [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Gracias.